# Jpa Repository save Inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have entity user

```
@Entity
@Data
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String username;

    private String password;

}
```

UserRepository

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserRepository, Long> {
    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public UserController(UserRepository userRepository, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @PostMapping("/sign-up")
    public void signUp(@RequestBody User user) {
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

In class UserController in signUp method userRepository.save(user) throw error     Inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound; should implement 'Repository.UserRepository

Comment: Annotate your userRepository with `@Autowired` in the Controller.

Comment: isnt this wrong `JpaRepository<UserRepository, Long>` . you should use User

Comment: Your next error will be `NullPointerException`

Comment: I have had a similar issue and it was in the repository and specifically the type you need to pass inside CrudRepository<>, you need to pass the domain class, namely ```User```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your Repository interface declaration isn't correct.

Change

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserRepository, Long>
```

to

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>
```

Comment: if the second solution not worked handle it                                                return customRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);

Answer (score 11):

For me, I got this error because `save(list)` method in the new version of spring boot does not support a `List of objects` as a parameter, so I replaced it with `saveAll(list)` so `xRepository.saveAll(list)`

Comment: This one worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The new version is generally 2.0 or higher having this change. They are restricting **Save()** method for Object. To save List  type data we have to use **saveAll()**.

Answer (score 0):

Following is another working solution

```js
return customRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the save method in the Repository Interface

`void save(List<? extends User> user);`

Answer (score 0):

Reason: Teacher Liao's spring boot uses 1.4.1.RELEASE, and the new version is generally 2.0 or higher.
Solution: Replace the findOne method

```
return repo.findById(id).orElse(null);
```